# Using DataGridView with BindingSource.DataSource=List<T>, need to bind to inherited type of T 

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource

I'm looking to resolve databinding to a Winforms datagridview using C# & .Net3.5. It's a bit involved and encompasses a few classes which I will provide code.

I have have an Interface defined as such:

```
public interface MyElement : IEditableObject {
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I next have an abstaract class that inherits from MyElement defined as such:

```
abstract public class MyElementAdapter : MyElement {
    private string myName;
    private string myDescription;
    private ModelElement myParent;
    public MyElementAdapter(MyElement parent) {
        myName = "New_Element";
        myDescription = string.Empty;
    }
    virtual public string Name {
        get { return myName; }
        set { myName = value; }
    }
    virtual public string Description {
        get { return myDescription; }
        set { myDescription = value; }
    }
    public MyElement Parent {
        get { return myParent; }
        set { myParent = value; }
    }
    public void BeginEdit() {
        // code to begin edit
    }
    public void CancelEdit() {
        // code to cancel edit
    }
    public void EndEdit() {
        // code to end edit
    }
}
```

There is a generic list of the interface type that is defined as such - its very basic and just retains a generic list of MyElements:

```
public class MyElementList : List<MyElement> {
    public MyElementList() {
    }
}
```

There is an inherited class named MyField which derives from MyElementAdapter defined as such:

```
public class MyField : MyElementAdapter {
    private int size;
    public MyField(MyElement parent) : base(parent) {
        size = 1;
    }
    public string MyFieldName {
        get { return this.Name; }
        set { this.Name = value;}
    }
    public string MyFieldDescription {
        get { return this.Description; }
        set { this.Description = value;}
    }
    public int Size {
        get { return size; }
        set { size = value; }
    }
}
```

There is a class which uses MyElementList where MyField is the List type:

```
public class MyRecordOfFields : MyElementAdapter {
    private MyElementList myMembers;
    public MyRecordOfFields(MyElement parent) : base(parent) {
        myMembers = new MyElementList();
    }
    public MyElementList MyMembers {
        get { return myMembers; }
        set { myMembers = value; }
    }
}
```

And finally, there is a form that I am using to edit an object of type MyRecordOfFields.

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    private BindingSource bindingSource1;
    private MyRecordOfFields myLocalFields;
    private DataGridView dgv;

    private Form1_Load() {
        myLocalFields = new MyRecordOfFields(null);
        MyField field1 = new MyField(null);
        field1.MyFieldName = "Field_1";
        field1.MyFieldDescription = "Description1";
        field1.Size = 3;
        myLocalFields.MyMembers.Add(field1);
        MyField field2 = new MyField(null);
        field2.MyFieldName = "Field_2";
        field2.MyFieldDescription = "Description2";
        field2.Size = 3;
        myLocalFields.MyMembers.Add(field2);
        MyField field3 = new MyField(null);
        field3.MyFieldName = "Field_3";
        field3.MyFieldDescription = "Description3";
        field3.Size = 3;
        myLocalFields.MyMembers.Add(field3);

        bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource1.AllowNew = true;

        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        int colIndex = dgv.Columns.Add("MyFieldName", "MyFieldName");
        dgv.Columns[colIndex].DataPropertyName = "MyFieldName";
        colIndex = dgv.Columns.Add("MyFieldDescription", "MyFieldDescription");
        dgv.Columns[colIndex].DataPropertyName = "MyFieldDescription";
        colIndex = dgv.Columns.Add("Size", "Size");
        dgv.Columns[colIndex].DataPropertyName = "Size";
        dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgv.AutoResizeColumns();

        bindingSource1.DataSource = myLocalFields.MyMembers;
        dgv.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        dgv.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

When this form is loaded, everything compiles and runs however when the form is displayed, the datagridview has 3 row but all blank.  I am trying to directly set the datagridview's datasource to the MyElementList in the MyRecordOfFields class however nothing is displayed expect for the number of rows added to the list.

When I don't set the datagridview's datasource to the list, but add each element in that list in a loop, data is displayed as it should.

The following line:

```
        bindingSource1.DataSource = myLocalFields.MyMembers;
```

Changed to a loop:

```
        foreach (MyElement me in myLocalFields.MyMembers) {
            // No casting needed due to inheritance
            bindingSource1.Add(me);
        }
```

And after I changed to a loop, I had to add event handlers for adding, deleting, and updating to the underlying data source which is myLocalFields (MyRecordOfFields.MyMembers).

Is there something I am missing or not doing correctly in my scenario?? I know it's a bit involved with the Interface & abstract classes, but I'm working from predefined implementations and so changing these underlying/basic classes is not an option.  Thank you in advance.

- Lorentz

**UPDATE:**
I've tried a few suggestion and to no avail nothing.  So my question is this: Is it possible for me to expose the inherited properties (like I designed the datagridview [columns]) of MyField by setting the bindingSource1.DataSource to the MyElementLIst in MyRecordOfFields.MyMembers property??

This is where I need some guidance: MyElement is an interface; MyElementAdapter is an abstract derived from MyElement; MyElementList is a generic list of MyElement; and MyField is derived from MyElementAdapter.  Adding MyElement or any derived class (ie MyField) to MyElementList works.  Yet it is these derived classes' properties I want to expose in the UI (datagridview, controls, etc.).

**UPDATE#2:**
Now that I have my datagridview bounded to my MyElementList everything is working fine.  I am now working on adding/deleting/updating myLocalFields.MyMembers list.  I've added a button with the following code:

```
private void AddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MyField field1 = new MyField(null);
    field1.MyFieldName = "Field_" + myLocalFields.MyMembers.Count + 1;
    field1.MyFieldDescription = "Description" + myLocalFields.MyMembers.Count + 1;
    field1.Size = myLocalFields.MyMembers.Count + 1;
    myLocalFields.MyMembers.Add(field1);
    ((BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource).ResetBindings(false);
}
```

When this method is done, I see that my underlying data (myLocalField.MyMembers) changes, but bindingSource1 and dataGridView1 do not.  In the past, any updates to the underlying data was done to the underlying data as well as the bindingsource - I would like to make changes to the underlying data and have that propogate to the bindingsource/datagridview.

I figured the following would take care of any changes to the datagridview but it doesn not:

```
    ((BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource).ResetBindings(false);
```

Is there another method that I need to use in order for me to update the datagridview without adding additional datagridview events?

Comment: "Pubic" members are always so difficult to work with.

Comment: You say everything compiles and runs, but you've posted code with numerous compile errors. Is there a reason you're not showing real code?

Comment: I am working from a pre established project and cannot change the underling application framework nor can I post actual code.  The code I post closely matches what I am working with.  I do apology for not posting the entire code - that would be intense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly:

- please consider accepting answers to your questions.
- please post code that compiles.

---

You **really** should prefix your interfaces with **I**. It makes your code easier to interpret.

You are setting your datasource to a `List<MyElement>`. That means the available properties it can bind to are `Name` and `Description`.

```
public interface MyElement : IEditableObject { 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}
```

But you're manually creating DataGridView columns which are bound to properties called `MyFieldName` and `MyFieldDescription` and `Size`. The data binder can't match up what you told it to expect with what you gave it.

When you do this, without first setting the datasource:

```
foreach (MyElement me in myLocalFields.MyMembers) {         
            bindingSource1.Add(me);         
        }
```

I believe the first object you add is what establishes the bindings, and in this case it's a `MyField`, which has the properties your DataGridView expects.

You have several options. Here are some of them in no particular order.

**Option 1.** Use `AutoGenerateColumns = true`, and delete all the code that creates columns manually.

**Option 2.** When you create the columns, use the MyElement property names:

```
int colIndex = dgv.Columns.Add("MyFieldName", "MyFieldName");  
dgv.Columns[colIndex].DataPropertyName = "Name";  
colIndex = dgv.Columns.Add("MyFieldDescription", "MyFieldDescription");  
dgv.Columns[colIndex].DataPropertyName = "Description";
```

**Option 3.** Cast the objects to `MyField`, so that the BindingSource generates the bindings for the properties you told the grid to expect:

Instead of this:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = myLocalFields.MyMembers;
```

Do this:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = myLocalFields.MyMembers.Cast<MyField>();
```

Hopefully you can see the theme here. The point is that you're currently combining explicitly bound columns with automatically created bindings, and the automatic bindings aren't what your columns are set up for. The options I've given you all address this problem in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the code and your answers. I've applied these answers, but I still do not have a bounded datagridview that exposes MyField's properties.

Comment: I've edited my answer and given three different options which I guarantee will work based on the example code you've posted. If this helps you please upvote and accept the answer, and I suggest you do the same for some of your other questions, as people are less inclined to help if they think you'll never accept/upvote.

Comment: Option 3 works for me!  Thank you Igby for the advice and help.

Comment: There is one last question with this: in my current solution (which has a predefined framework) I do not see the Cast<T>() method in my intellisence for MyElementList.  However, in the code provide here, Case<T>() method is an option.  I have structured the example code 'exactly' as it is structured in my solution.  Am I missing a concept related to Generic List implementation? There is a ConvertAll<TResult>() method and I tried this and it works.  Not sure why...?

Comment: Cast<T>() is part of LINQ; it's an extension method defined on the Enumerable class. You'll need to add `using System.Linq;` to the file, then Intellisense will show it.

Comment: Thank you.  The predefined framework had the all references of Linq removed.  That will change with new implementations/upgrades.  I appreciate all the help.