# how to map data from a data dictionary to datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data dictionary which is as follows:

```
Key  Value

1    ron k polito
2    Ryan s Winslate
```

I am trying to display the Value column in a datagridview with three different columns firstname, midname and lastname. The below statement names.getnames().ToList() retrieves the names (value) from the data dictionary.

```
datagridview1.DataSource = names.getnames().ToList();
```

By moving the list into datagridview creates exactly same number of rows as total number of count retrieved by the data dictionary, but it doesnot display the anything. just the blank rows appear.

I am new to C#, any suggestion how can I fix this.

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
             List<localname> lname_list = new List<localname>();
             var l_names = names.getnames().ToList();
             foreach(var lcname in l_names)
             {
                 string[] wrd = lcname.Split(' ');
                 localname lv = new localname();
                 lv.mylocal(wrd[0], wrd[1], wrd[2]);
                 lname_list.Add(lv);
             }
             datagridview1.DataSource = lname_list;
             ShowDialog();
```

Comment: asp.net ,WinForms, WPF ,under what?

Comment: getNames retrives all the values from a data dictionary.

Comment: Seems like we see a "empty DataGridView rows" question every week. You need to familiarize yourself with how databinding works between DataGridView a and its datasource. Specifically, if you manually create columns (instead of using AutoGenerateColumns = true on the DGV), you must ensure that the DataPropertyName of the columns match up with public properties on the type of object you provide as a datasource (or the type within the list if the datasource is a list). You haven't provided enough code to properly asess your problem. Show the type used for Values in the dictionary.

Comment: Reading this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692132/using-datagridview-with-bindingsource-datasource-listt-need-to-bind-to-inheri/10692925#10692925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LINQ you can do this with few lines of code.

Provided you have a Custom class like

```
class CustomerName
{
   public string FirstName { get; set;}
   public string MidName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and your dictionary value has the first. mid, last names (meaning the value should always have 3 parts); you can do this.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dic.Add(1, "ron k polito");
dic.Add(2, "Ryan s Winslate");

var dicNames = (from a in (dic.Select(b => b.Value).Select(c => c.Split(' ')).AsEnumerable()) select new CustomerName { FirstName = a[0], MidName = a[1], LastName = a[2] }).ToList();            

dataGridView1.DataSource = dicNames;
```

**Ouput**

[image]

Comment: I am not sure....but still I am not getting any data. is it because I am using showdialog() ???

Comment: why do you need ShowDialog()? ShowDialog is there to open another form as a dialog. For example you have a button in Form1 and when you click if you want to open Form2 as a dialog, in the Form1_Click event you will call Form2instance.ShowDialog();

Comment: Can you put the code under Form_Load event and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you everyone ... It worked... The problem was the datagrid propertyname was not set.  Thanks again!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You will need a List of a specified POCO that will be used to populate the DataGrid. The POCO will contain properties that will represent each column you want..example:

```
public class Name
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

Inside your form, you will populate the list based on your getNames function.

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Name> namesList = new List<Name>();

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn firstNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        makeColumn.DataPropertyName = "First";
        makeColumn.HeaderText = "First Name";

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn middleNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        modelColumn.DataPropertyName = "Middle";
        modelColumn.HeaderText = "Middle Name";

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn lastNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        yearColumn.DataPropertyName = "Last";
        yearColumn.HeaderText = "Last Name";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(firstNameColumn);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(middleNameColumn);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(lastNameColumn);

        for (int i = 0; i < names.getNames().Length; i++)
        {
            // TODO create new Name object. 
            // TODO set properties in new Name object accordingly.
            // TODO add name object to namesList once properties have been set.
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = namesList;
    }
```

Instead of a List, you can also use an ObservableCollection, or BindingList

Comment: I tried as mentioned above but still no luck... I get 2 empty rows in datagridview. but no data.

Comment: @Csharp_learner Make sure the correct "fields to use" are specified in the Grid. It uses reflection and dynamic binding of the objects in the data-source.

Comment: @Csharp_learner sounds like the data is not getting displayed correctly.. If you have two empty rows, the data "is there", but somewhere the binding is incorrect. Try the updated code.

Comment: Thank you everyone ... It worked... The problem was the datagrid propertyname was not set.  Thanks again!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you need nothing extra coding.
just do this

**Grd.DataSource=null;**

**Grd.DataSource = DictionaryObject.Values.ToList();**

thats it